# bevel Modifier causing troubles

Tags: modeling, bevel

I attached a picture illustrating my problem. For some reason, there is a random indent when I use the bevel modifier, and I have no idea why it is there.[image]

Comment: maybe vertices overlapping? Try a alt M > Merge by Distance. Or an inner face?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a face that has 2 cuts across, while the neighboring face has none. 
1. Make sure there isn't a hole in your mesh at that point by moving any of the 2 left vertices right next to the hole.
2. I would strongly suggest to add 2 loop cuts to the left of the object as well.

One of those is causing your indent. (Unless I looked at the wrong portion of your screenshot, marking the problematic area somehow might help)

Comment: I did this really late at night, and I read the modifier incorrectly. I accidentally applied a subdivision surface modifier instead of a bevel modifier. Still some issues with shade smooth, but I think that may be because my topology is off.